# SQL - move data from 1 table to another in a range

Tags: php, mysql, sql, joomla

I have 1 table q3ept_content there is 8000 entries.
i want to to move data from 1 to 500 in a range into a new table2

In table q3ept_content i have many columns but one id column i have through that i can move all 500 rows..

please tell me the SQL query

1 between 500 move to new table .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: @jay Balanchard 8000 Entries i want to move in to a new table but in a parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
       SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
       FROM q3ept_content  WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 500;
```

or if you want just first 500 records from `q3ept_content`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Col1, Col2, Col3)
       SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3
       FROM q3ept_content LIMIT 500;
```

`Col1, Col2, Col3` - columns you want to move

**NOTE:** Make sure you have `AUTO INCREMENT` `id` field in `table2`

Comment: you answer is almost perfect but i have already ID column can i move through id.

Comment: you're welcome, glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

This can help you out to `SELECT` from one table with range/limit/condition and `INSERT` into another table.

```
INSERT INTO tbl_temp2 (id,column2,column3,column4)
  SELECT tbl_temp1.id,tbl_temp1.column2,tbl_temp1.column3,tbl_temp1.column4
FROM tbl_temp1 LIMIT 500;
```

**See More** :https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html